# How to reduce gaps between sections in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, web, visual-web-developer

I'm editing a CSS template named 2083 SteakHouse (http://www.tooplate.com/view/2083-steak-house).

I removed the "Meet our chefs" section in HTML and in `style.css`

- The problem now is there is an ugly gap between food menu and food gallery. (Please download and see it yourself).
- Please view the image below to see what I'm talking about.

[image: IMAGE click here]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: do you have code ?

Comment: there must be an empty section or a div in your code..would be better if u shared the code

Answer (score 0):

You just reduce you **Menu** section bottom padding and **Gallery** Section top padding. Use like this.

```
section#menu {padding-bottom:50px;}
section#gallery {padding-top:50px;}
```

It will be working for you. Also, you reduce more padding if you want.

Comment: It worked !! Thanks a lot ... I want to know what "section#menu" is and how did it change the food gallery and the other sections. I'm not so good at CSS.